# Spring-Data-Neo4j: relationshipEntity return only graphId for nodes.

Tags: java, neo4j, entity-relationship, spring-data-neo4j

I am creating an example using `Spring-Data-Neo4j` . In this, perform CRUD operations, and all operation run successfully. But when i fetch the relationa ship collection from entity, it return only `graphId` for nodes, and other values are null. Following is my code. If i do something wrong, please correct me.

Entities:

```
@NodeEntity
@ToString(callSuper=true, exclude={"movies"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, exclude = {"name", "movies"})
public class Person extends BaseEntity{

 @Getter @Setter
 @Indexed(unique = true)
 private Long id;
 @Getter @Setter
 private String name;
 @Getter @Setter
 @RelatedToVia(type = RelationshipTypes.FRIEND, elementClass = FriendsRelationship.class, direction = Direction.BOTH)
 private Set<FriendsRelationship> friends;
}

@RelationshipEntity(type=RelationshipTypes.FRIEND)
public class FriendsRelationship extends BaseEntity{

 @StartNode
 @Getter @Setter
 private Person person;
 @EndNode
 @Getter @Setter
 private Person friend;
 @Getter @Setter
 private String friendsType;
}
```

Create Relationship:

```
public FriendsRelationship createRelationshipBetweenPersons(Person person, Person friend, 
        Class<FriendsRelationship> relationshipEntity, String friendshipType) {
    FriendsRelationship relationship = neo4jTemplate.createRelationshipBetween(person, friend, relationshipEntity, friendshipType, true);
    neo4jTemplate.save(relationship);
    return relationship;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="find-person-by-id", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String findPersonById(long id, Model model) {
    Person person =  personService.findPersonByProperty("id", id);
    model.addAttribute("actor", person);
    model.addAttribute("personFriends", person.getFriends());
    return "person/view-person-detail";
}
```

In controller, when i fetch the person, the person fetch successfully,  but i fetch the friends, it contain `start_node` with same person object, but `end_node` contain person object with `graphId` value only, others values are null.

Answer (score 0):

For solve this problem, we need to add `@Fetch` annotation at start-node and end-node in `FriendsRelationship` entity, like as below:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type=RelationshipTypes.FRIEND)
public class FriendsRelationship extends BaseEntity{

 @Fetch @StartNode
 @Getter @Setter
 private Person person;
 @Fetch @EndNode
 @Getter @Setter
 private Person friend;
 @Getter @Setter
 private String friendsType;
}
```

Now the data fetch successfully.

Comment: But I wouldn't do that, use template.fetch(friendship.person) if your really need it. Otherwise you'll load the whole graph into memory.

Comment: @MichaelHunger To use template.fetch(friendship.person) does that mean the identifier person in the friendship relationship class needs to be made public?

Is there any other way to fetch specific values of variables? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DengkeSha if you you want to fetch values, without `getter/setter` make variables public other wise create `getter` for variable.